# Does many AWS OpsWorks apps = many stacks? What about shared resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

I have a rails app and a rails API app both setup in an OpsWorks stack. It seems by default it wants to deploy both rails apps to any rails layer instance. When I start an instance it will deploy both apps to it. I was looking to have them on separate instances. I understand I can just create another stack, but what about shared resources like a MongoDB or caching server.

Answer (score 0):

You can override opsworks "**`deploy::default`**" with your own deploy recipe under layer settings and create layer-specific recipes that would deploy only the specified app to this layer not all of them.